# Crossfading images with CSS Keyframes not working

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm using keyframes in CSS for the first time.

It didn't work on the 2 browsers I tested (Safari and Chrome) and I learned that all keyframe-related properties need browser prefixes, so I added -webkit- but it still won't work

The purpose is to have the images crossfade every 10 seconds, but I only see Image2 constantly.

Here's the code for the div:

```
<div id="cf">
<img class="bottom" src="Image1.jpg" width = "300px">
<img class="top" src="Image2.jpg" width = "300px" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cf {
position:relative;
width:300px;
margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
position:absolute;
left:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}


@keyframes cf3FadeInOut {

0% {
opacity:1;
}

45% {
opacity:1;
}

55% {
opacity:0;
}

100% {
opacity:0;
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {

0% {
    -webkit-opacity:1;
}

45% {
    -webkit-opacity:1;
}

55% {
    -webkit-opacity:0;
}

100% {
    -webkit-opacity:0;
}

}

#cf3 img.top {
animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 10s;
animation-direction: alternate;

-webkit-animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-duration: 10s;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a mistake calling the animation. the id `#cf3` doesn't exist. The rest works fine (but delete the -webkit- for opacity, that css property doesn't need it)

```
#cf img.top {
animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 10s;
animation-direction: alternate;

-webkit-animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-duration: 10s;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/hkhhy98q/)**